# Remove whitespace, but do so last?

Tags: whitespace, antlr, lexer

I am attempting to parse Lua, which depends on whitespace in some cases due to the fact that it doesn't use braces for scope. I figure that by throwing out whitespace only if another rule doesn't match is the best way, but i have no clue how to do that. Can someone help me?

Comment: I have no experience with Lua, so could you perhaps give an example when a white space cannot be ignored (or put on `$channel=HIDDEN`)?

Comment: for instance, you have the if tatement which is like this: `if `*`condition`*` then `*`block`*` end` and the spaces are important so that the identifying words are read properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Lua's documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html), I see no need to take spaces into account.

The parser rule `ifStatement`:

```
ifStatement
    :    'if' exp 'then' block ('elseif' exp 'then' block 'else' block)? 'end'
    ;

exp
    :    /* todo */
    ;

block
    :    /* todo */
    ;
```

should match both:

```
if j==10 then print ("j equals 10") end
```

and:

```
if j<10 then
    print ("j < 10")
elseif j>100 then
    print ("j > 100")
else
    print ("j >= 10 && j <= 100")
end
```

No need to take spaces into account, AFAIK. So you can just add:

```
Space
    :    (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n'){$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

in your grammar.

**EDIT**

It seems there is a Lua grammar on the ANTLR wiki: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1178608849736/Lua.g

And it seems I my suggestion for an if statement slightly differs from the grammar above:

```
'if' exp 'then' block ('elseif' exp 'then' block)* ('else' block)? 'end'
```

which is the correct one, as you can see.

Comment: Bu the problem is that i'm trying to match the behavior of lua's compiler, which won't compile `ifj==10thenprint('j equals 10')end` since neither ifj or thenprint are valid keywords.

Comment: Parsing `ifj==10thenprint('j equals 10')end` wouldn't be accepted as a valid if statement. There's no need for you to specify spaces between them. Hiding the spaces will suffice.